# What's the idiomatic way of obtaining the "default" C++ include base path?

Tags: directory-structure, c++

I'm building a command-line for some utility which, for some reason, needs the C++ include root, e.g. `/usr/include/c++/10` (for libstdc++ of GCC-10). My question is: How do I determine what that path is, on my system? Or rather, what's the idiomatic way of doing that?

Obviously, there could be an override with `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH`, but that case is easy. What should I be doing when there are multiple installed C++ compilers, including multiple versions of GCC? "Manually" sort the version numbers under `/usr/include`? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

Good question.

On my machine, I get this:

```
$ find /usr/include -name string
/usr/include/c++/8/debug/string
/usr/include/c++/8/experimental/string
/usr/include/c++/8/string
/usr/include/c++/9/debug/string
/usr/include/c++/9/experimental/string
/usr/include/c++/9/string
/usr/include/c++/10/debug/string
/usr/include/c++/10/experimental/string
/usr/include/c++/10/string
/usr/include/c++/11/debug/string
/usr/include/c++/11/experimental/string
/usr/include/c++/11/string
/usr/include/c++/12/debug/string
/usr/include/c++/12/experimental/string
/usr/include/c++/12/string
```

To find out which is being used, we could use gcc to process an empty program and print out its search paths:

```
$ g++ -E -xc++ - -v < /dev/null
...
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include/c++/12
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/12
 /usr/include/c++/12/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
...
```

Explanation of the flags:

- `-E`: Preprocess only; do not compile, assemble or link.
- `-xc++`: Specify the language (C++)
- `-`: Take input from stdin instead of a file
- `-v`: Display the programs invoked by the compiler.
- `< /dev/null`: Send emptiness to stdin.

It might be better to also add the `CFLAGS` or `CPPFLAGS` from  your original makefile and parse the output of your compilation.  That's because other paths could be prepended by your makefile using `-I...`.

Example:

```
$ g++ -E -xc++ - -v -I/tmp < /dev/null
...
#include <...> search starts here:
 /tmp                                 <-- NEW because of -I/tmp
 /usr/include/c++/12
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/12
 /usr/include/c++/12/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
...
```

Comment: I understand that this is something I _could_ do, but what's important to me what's the idiom, or custom, that's also used elsewhere. Also - what if there is no gcc? Or there is, but clang++ is the default C++ compiler?